# can I put a Where clause on *just one field*?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have data in one table.

I can write sql to return the number of cases per staff member, like this:

```
select Staff, Count(Staff) as cases
from caseload
group by Staff
```

I can also write sql to return the number of **old** cases per staff member, like this:

```
select Staff, count(Staff) as oldcases
from caseload
where "Days from lc" >= 21
group by Staff
```

**My questions is**, how do I combine these two queries to get one result set with three columns: Staff, cases, oldcases? Each row should have a Staff member name, number of cases for that staff member, and number of cases for that staff member that are older than 21 days.

What it seems like I should do is put the where clause on just the oldcases field, but that can't be right. I know I'm missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
select Staff, Count(Staff) as cases,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN "Days from lc" >= 21 THEN 1 END) AS oldcases
from caseload
group by Staff;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select Staff, Count(*) as cases,
       sum(case when "Days from lc" >= 21 then 1 else 0 end) as older_cases
from caseload
group by Staff;
```

I would discourage you from naming columns with special characters in them.  Having to escape the names every time you reference them is a hassle.